# Import CSV File into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I'm struggling with a problem.

So what i try is to import a csv file into a table.

Code:

```
-
```

But here's the catch: When import a file. It says; Success!, but nothing had imported.

What am I not seeing?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
-
```

From the edited code I only getting the message: $satus=toegevoegd. Translated: Added to database. But there is no data in the table... I really dont know what im doing wrong.

EDIT 2;

```
-
```

Comment: Success message is conditioned to having a not-null $FILES array, not to succeding at $db->query statements. Try to get output from those to see if any SQL error shows up

Comment: Also, add a debug somewhere in your `while()` to ensure that the code does enter this block.

Comment: @Alfabravo Thanks for your reaction. I added some messages at different point so I can get more specific.

The code is is on the original post with some explaination at the bottom.

Comment: @NaeiKinDus Thanks for your reaction. I added some messages at different point so I can get more specific. The code is is on the original post with some explaination at the bottom.

Comment: Still not checking what `query()` method returned. I don't know how are you creating $db object but doing something like `$result = $db->query(...` and then checking the content of `$result` will provide a real answer. You will always get `$qstring` assigned as `query` is surely handling the SQL exception so you won't get a nasty error message. Do you mind including dbConn.php?

Comment: @Alfabravo, Thanks for your help so far! 

Im currently working on what you and symcbean said.

Ive updated the post with de dbconfig.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of good advice in the help centre - notably [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

As it stands there is no error checking in your code (which should be required for production use, never mind development). That the script ends with a redirect makes it rather hard to report detailed events for debugging (but these can be written to log files).

> ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

I am guessing this is the mysqli extension you are using here - if a query or connection fails, it does not trigger an eror in PHP, you need to poll mysqli_error() and/or check the return value from the operation.

The SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT is very inefficient - a better approach would be to

- use REPLACE if you always want to override the existing data,
- OR, if you want to be a bit more selective

  - attempt the insert then handle duplicate key conflicts when they arise
  - or use a trigger to multiplex the insert/update behaviour.

Depending on how the CSV is constructed you will get an error for the last line in the file - you might want to check `4<=count($line)` before attempting to access the record.

Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: Thanks! for the explained information! Will work on it :) As you know I'm a beginnen in PHP :P